# Can local supersymmetry be characterized entirely in terms of observables?

Tags: supersymmetry, quantum-gravity, gauge-invariance, observables, supergravity

Global symmetries can be defined through their effect on observables. In contrast, quantum theories are often constructed with the help of symmetries that leave observables invariant, like the asymptotically-trivial $U(1)$ gauge transformations in QED. Reference 1 emphasizes that such symmetries are generally not intrinsic properties of the theory, because the same theory (with the same observables) may sometimes be constructed in different ways that have different gauge symmetries:

> it seems clear that there is no unique answer to the question “what is the gauge group of abstract quantum field theory X?” This is to be distinguished from the case of global symmetry... That said, there are certainly unambiguous physical phenomena which we typically *associate* with gauge symmetry...

Reference 1 then goes on to propose and study a definition that tries to capture the *observable* characteristics of gauge symmetry, in cases where the theory is in the Coulomb phase (also called the free charge phase). The definition proposed in reference 1 assumes that the group being gauged is compact.

Local supersymmetry is an important example of a gauge symmetry in studies of quantum gravity, but the definition proposed in reference 1 doesn't apply in this case because the group being gauged is not compact. It may not even be a *group* at all, as noted in references 2 and 3. Sometimes it's only a symmetry *algebra*. Another complication here is that a quantum theory with local supersymmetry is necessarily a theory of quantum gravity. That might make the question too difficult, so I'd be content with a provisional answer based on classical supergravity.

**Quesiton:** Does local supersymmetry have any known characterization using only observables, independently of how the theory is constructed?

Keep in mind that a fermion field cannot be an observable. This should go without saying, but I'm saying it anyway to emphasize once again that the question is about what can be characterized using only *observables*.

Related: [Can supersymmetries change under dualities, like gauge symmetries can?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/572002)

---

1. Section 3 in Harlow and Ooguri, *Symmetries in Quantum Field Theory and Quantum Gravity* (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.05338)
2. Footnote 78 in section 7 of Harlow and Ooguri (reference 1)
3. Slide 35 in Kaplan (2007), *Supersymmetry on the Lattice*, (http://www.int.washington.edu/users/dbkaplan/Schladming2007.pdf)